# 404 Error on a WordPress Website, Error disappears for a while and again appears

Tags: plugins, permalinks, 404-error, cloudflare

On website **revel.pk**, I am facing 404 Errors from last night. The error disappears for a while and again appears. I noticed that when the website is facing an error I just go to the **permalink setting** page and without any change in permalink settings 404 error disappears. But sadly after some time, the error appears again.

I am using WP Rocket Plugin. On the last day, I linked my site with Cloudflare but after that, I started facing this problem and then I removed Cloudflare. But problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your htaccess file is being changed. I'd look at that file content and time stamp after the 404 happens. (Although it is possible to make changes to a file without changing the file's time stamp - I've seen it done on a hacked site.)

Redoing the permalink settings rewrites the htaccess file, which is why I suggest looking there.

You might also do a search of all plugin's code for 'htaccess' to see if there is code that is directly changing that file. There might also be a filter that can be called to reset permalinks but can't find it right now.

You might also consider that perhaps your site has some malware. There are many googles/bings/ducks on how to figure that out.

Comment: I checked my htaccess file. It's empty. What do you think now?

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/ .  There should be an htaccess, although some research seems to indicate that a default setting in Settings, Permalinks doesn't need htaccess. I always use one. WP will create the htaccess if you change Permalinks to other than default.